# What values should I use for light paths->Max Bounces of diamond/gemstone for realistic effect?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Values i kept now are :
Total : 12 , Diffuse : 4, Glossy : 4, Transmission: 12, Vol : 0, Transparent : 8

Blend File : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_X1BB0xevVQzawKQSv6smmFPxgQh2sPN/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: EDIT: you don't really need high transmission, it can stay on 4 or 6 and raising it up doesn't seem to change how it looks, Glossy and Total are what you need to try to rise. I tried to change Glossy from 0 to 100 and I could still see a new reflection even at 100+, keep in mind however that you still need to optimize it for your hardware, change Total to the number of Glossy that you will find as good... realism is still a bit subjective and someone will say something else

Comment: Thanks @MikoCG issue have resolved.

Comment: no problem, dispersion and reflections in diamonds need a lot of bounces to look right because in reality there are hundreds of reflections that gives them that shiny look